# Rails 3 routing. How to create /controller/id/action routing format for specific action taking place?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

Ok so this is a basic routing question for a rails 3 application. I have a controller called contact_infos. For the edit action I want to match the route like the following /contact_infos/id/action. The reason I'm doing this is specifically for ajax functionality. Here's what I've done so far. This route worked fine.

```
match ':controller(/:id(/:action))(.:format)'
```

But this route breaks my catch-all route of.

```
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

so it is not acceptable for my application.

I know I could target my specific route in the following way

```
  controller :contact_infos do

  end
```

But I'm unsure how to match the url as /contact_infos/id/action only for the edit action without breaking any other contact_infos actions.

Any ideas?
If you give the right answer I will definitely rate you up.
Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Well I just figured it out. The correct answer is the following!! controller :contact_infos do match 'contact_infos/:id/edit' => 'contact_infos#edit' end

Comment: In this case you not only could, but [should](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) answer your own question, so it can be useful for others.

Answer (score 0):

Try using through the following sytax...

```
  match "contact_infos/:id/edit" , :to => "contact_infos#edit", :as => 'contact_infos_edit'
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that whilst not part of your question, that a catch all route is a very bad idea.

This has been considered dangerous for some time, and is not recommended.  It will allow the app to respond to actions for all HTTP methods (e.g. GET for things which should really be PUT).  This exposes you to CSRF attacks, as the CSRF token is only required for PUT, POST and DELETE requests..

You should always explicitly route using the routing helpers for all resources you're making available, to ensure the app will only respond to correct requests (e.g. DELETE request for a destroy acttion)